# MIT Integration bee 2023 Regular Season $\int_0^\pi x\sin^4(x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, contest-math

How do I find $$\int_0^\pi x\sin^4xdx$$? This is the 8th question in the MIT integration bee regular season. You could find integrals here. Integration by parts directly is out of question. I thought of substituting $1-\cos^2x=\sin^2x$, but that is just more complicated. Any ideas?

Comment: Use $x\leftrightarrow\pi-x$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let
$$I=\int_0^\pi x\sin^4x\,\mathrm{d}x$$
substituting $u=\pi-x$ you have:
$$I=\int_0^\pi (\pi-x)\sin^4(\pi-x)\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\pi (\pi-x)\sin^4x\mathrm{d}x=\pi\int_0^\pi \sin^4x\mathrm{d}x-I $$
Hence
$$I=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^\pi \sin^4x\mathrm{d}x=\frac{3\pi^2}{16}$$

Comment: Jazak Allah for your answer! But I wonder what the formula for integrals with $\sin^{2n}(x)$ as the integrals. I forgot it unfortunately:(

Comment: @KamalSaleh Salam, there are reduction formulas, but these "special" cases are known

Answer (score 6):

Without using symmetry one can make use of the power reducing formula
$$
\sin ^4 x = \frac{3-4\cos2x+\cos4x}{8}
$$
whence
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin ^4 x \,dx =\frac{3}{8}\int_{0}^{\pi} x\,dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^\pi x\cos2x\, dx +\frac{1}{8}\int_{0}^{\pi}x\cos4x\, dx\tag{0}
$$
so
$$
\int_{0}^{\pi}x\sin ^4 x \,dx =\frac{3}{16}\pi^2
$$
since the the final two integrals in $(0)$ are equal to zero by an application of integration by parts.